# How to add character amounts in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character, addition

So I have an array of strings and need to take the amount of characters in each string and add them together to get 1 total. How would I go about doing this?

Here is the array:

```
public class Final21 {
   public static String getLongString(String[] array) {

      String[] names = {"bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack"};

   }
}
```

I am not adding indexes, but the amount of characters in each string. 
Example: bob has 3 characters, tomtomjack has 10 characters, if you add them it would be 13

Attempts:

```
       public static int countAllLetters(String[] array) {

      String[] names = {"bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack"};                

         int sum = 0;
         for(String s : array)
            sum += s.length();
               return sum;

      int amountOfLetters = countAllLetters(names);
         System.out.println(amountOfLetters);

   }
```

Gives error:

```
Final21.java:62: error: unreachable statement
      int amountOfLetters = countAllLetters(names);
          ^
Final21.java:65: error: missing return statement
   }
   ^
2 errors
```

Comment: `String`s have a `length()` method, which returns a number of characters in it. Use it

Comment: @ Fureeish  I tried that but that requires hard coding the names of the strings, my professor said not to hard code it. So if you remove or add to the array, it should remove or add the appropriate amount of characters

Comment: I'm sorry? No, that does not require that. For example, given your `names` array, this: `names[0].length()` would return `3`.

Comment: @Fureeish Wouldnt i need to hardcode in which index? like index 0, 1, 2 etc... and then take that result and add it together?

Comment: No, you can run it in a loop. No need for hardcoding

Comment: Disregard my last comment. It seems you're trying to return the `sum`, but the method declares a `String` return type. If you need to return the `sum`, then the method should be declared `public static int getLongString`. If you're trying to combine the names into one long `String`, then you need to concat them: `StringBuilder longString = new StringBuilder(); for(String s : names) { builder.append(s); } return builder.toString();`

Comment: @VinceEmigh yea if i make it return sum then it returns back error "int cannot be converted to string"

Comment: Do you want to return the `sum`, or a `String` containing all the names? If you want the `sum`, then you need to change the return type of your method from `String` to `int` (see my previous comment). Also, if you want the method to return the `sum`, you may want to change the name of that method to better describe that behabior. The current method name suggests itll return a long `String` containing all the contents from the array.

Comment: I am trying to return the sum of all the characters if they are added together, so there are 27 characters right now. I need it to return back 27 then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Java 8+ solution, refer to [this answer by Aominè](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50184366/2398375).

In the comments, you say you can't use Java 8. This answer exposes a solution for pre-Java 8 environments.

---

If you want to return an `int` containing the combined amount of characters from every `String` in the array, you need to change the return type of your method.

```
public static int countAllLetters(String[] array)
```

Notice how I changed the name to better express the behavior of this method.

To implement it, simply loop through the `array` and add together the `length()` of each `String`:

```
public static int countAllLetters(String[] array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(String s : array)
        sum += s.length();
    return sum;
}
```

This would be used as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = { "bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack" };
    int amountOfLetters = countAllLetters(names);

    System.out.println(amountOfLetters);
}
```

So your finished result would be:

```
public class YourClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = { "bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack" };
        int amountOfLetters = countAllLetters(names);

        System.out.println(amountOfLetters);
    }

    public static int countAllLetters(String[] array) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(String s : array)
            sum += s.length();
        return sum;
    }
}
```

<sup>[Click here to test using an online compiler](https://ideone.com/g9GCff)</sup>

Also notice how I don't declare the `names` array inside the method. Instead, I declared it outside of the array, then passed it into the method as an argument. This allows the method to be reusable for different arrays, rather than a single hard-coded `names` array.

---

However, if you want to return a `String` of array's content combined (based on the name & return type you're showing in your question), you need to keep the return type of your method as `String`, and concat the items from the array:

```
public static String concat(String[] array) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : array)
        builder.append(s);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I used the first method and it seems to be working. Now I just have to figure out how to print out the total of the added characters

Comment: @CaptainMuffenz Edited my post's usage example to include printing. Let me know if you have any further issues with this.

Comment: It says error: <identifier> expected
      System.out.println(amountOfLetters);

Comment: @CaptainMuffenz Please include the full attempt in your post. You may be attempting this in an invalid scope. The usage code should be within another method, such as the `main` method (the entry point for Java programs - where the program starts it's execution). I'm assuming you put that code in the field of a class, opposed to inside another method.

Comment: I was able to fix that error but now i have a new one... RIP... I updated the original question with the attempt

Comment: @CaptainMuffenz That's because you put the usage code within `countAllLetters`. This will lead to a `StackOverflowException`. I've added a link to an online compiler that expresses how this code is to be used. Please let me know of any further project requirements which may invalidate this answer (such as not being able to declare a `main` method). All standard stand-alone, non-FX Java applications require a `main` method to launch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170401/discussion-between-vince-emigh-and-captainmuffenz).

Answer (score 7):

Using the stream API, it can be done as follows:

```
 int sum = Arrays.stream(names)
                .mapToInt(String::length)
                .sum();
```

Comment: I got 2 errors trying to compile that: 

"Final21.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
      int sum = Arrays.stream(names)
                ^
  symbol:   variable arrays
  location: class Final21
Final21.java:52: error: invalid method reference
                .mapToInt(String::length)
                          ^
  non-static method length() cannot be referenced from a static context
2 errors "

Comment: @CaptainMuffenz the code mentioned above will only work as of JDK8. an alternative is `int sum = 0;
        for (String n: names)
            sum += n.length();`

Comment: @CaptainMuffenz We are now on Java 10. If you're using Java 7, you may wanna look into upgrading if possible. As for all the compiler errors you're getting from these solutions, could you edit your attempt into your original post (without replacing the original code - simply include your attempts at the bottom) to ensure you're implementing them correctly? These answers seem fine to me, which makes me believe you may be making a mistake somewhere while implementing.

Comment: @VinceEmigh my school uses the version of java before 8

Comment: @VinceEmigh I added my most recent attempt to the question