# Using iterator object to loop throuh arraylist and check if it is higher than a value

Tags: java, iterator

I have a static method and I am required to complete it.

What I have to do is use an Iterator to check if the y coordinate is greater than highest value and return that value. Here's what I have now.

```
import java.awt.*;

public static Point highestPoint(List<Point> points) {
Iterator<Point> pointIterator = points.iterator();
int highest = 0;
Point highestPoint = null;
while (pointIterator.hasNext()) {
   pointIterator.next()
    if (points.getY() > highest) {
      highest = points.get(Y);
  }

}


return highestPoint;
}
```

When I run my code, I get a syntax error saying this:

```
Main.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
  if (points.getY() > highest) {
            ^
symbol:   method getY()
location: variable points of type List<Point>
Main.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
      highest = points.getY();
                      ^
symbol:   method getY()
location: variable points of type List<Point>
2 errors
```

Comment: I'd use `points.stream().mapToInt(Point::getY).max().orElse(IllegalArgumentException::new)`

Comment: Nobody downvoted this yet? 1. You cant use getY() on List 2. Why do you need to use iterator, any specific use case? Use stream max function

Comment: @Deepak [If you think thats bad..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184341/how-to-add-character-amounts-in-an-array). SO strayed away from it's standard of a repository of high quality Q&A. It has shifted towards "*Just fix their problem. They no longer have that problem, and you'll gain rep. Rep attracts attention to your profile.*" I used to be [about quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321336/i-gamify-stack-overflow-how-do-i-stop) ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution)). Now look at me.

Comment: @Vince, I was only being sarcastic and funny at start. No offence but I was asking simple question why do you need iterator. If there is no need to create additional interator object other than finding max then use stream

Comment: You clearly don't know what the downvote button is used for, @Deepak

Comment: @Deepak It's not funny at all. You are right, this should be downvoted & closed as duplicate. If you find that funny, then this site must be a joke to you. Did you downvote this? (rhetorical question - there are no downvotes on this post based on the OP's reputation history, so that would be a no) I don't see any duplicate flags on this post. Rather than attempting to be funny with horrible jokes (which aren't even jokes), how about contributing? You say use `Stream` without knowing if his environment supports Java 8+...

Comment: Thats what I was asking (JE8?) when I asked any specific use case?

Comment: @Deepak You didn't ask that. Same could be achieved with a pre-Java 8 environment without using an iterator directly (for loops). Instead of arguing over this, why not contribute an answer? Or say "*Are you using Java 8? You could do the same with a `Stream`*", or "*Why use an iterator when you could use an enhanced for loop?*" opposed to your currently cryptic way of asking about which environment he is using.

Answer (score 0):

points is a List and you cannot hence call getY() on it. You need to get the Point object first from the call to pointIterator.next() and then call getY() method on it.

```
while (pointIterator.hasNext()) {
    Point point = pointIterator.next();
    if (point.getY() > highest) {
        highest = point.get(Y);
     }
}
```

You can also achieve the same using streams and by removing the entire boilerplate code

```
Point highest = points.stream().max((p1, p2) -> p1.getY() > p2.getY() ? 1 : -1).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the result of `next()` in a variable

```
Point currentPoint = pointIterator.next();
```

Check if the current `highestPoint` is `null`. If so, set the `currentPoint` as the highest:

```
if(highestPoint == null)
    highestPoint = currentPoint;
```

Otherwise, compare the highest point to the current:

```
if(highestPoint == null)
    highestPoint = currentPoint;
else if(highestPoint.getY() < currentPoint.getY())
    highestPoint = currentPoint;
```

No need for `int highest`. Your final result would be:

```
public Point highestPoint(List<Point> points) {
    Point highestPoint = null;

    Iterator<Point> pointIterator = points.iterator();
    while(pointIterator.hasNext()) {
        Point currentPoint = pointIterator.next();

        if(highestPoint == null || highestPoint.getY() < currentPoint.getY())
            highestPoint = currentPoint;
    }

    return highestPoint;
}
```